# When a Class implements a listener interface to listen for changes recorded in a class extending BroadcastReceiver, nothing happens

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, listener, connectivity

I have one Activity class which needs to perform certain functions according to the changes it feels from the `ConnectivityReceiver` Class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` for changes in Internet Connectivity

Following are the two classes as implementing the interface in the `ConnectivityReceiver` class

But the required feature does not work the way it is desired. Infact, nothing at all happens. Kindly suggest ways to be able to do this.

- MyActivity

  ```
  public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {

      private EditText editText;
      private static MyActivity mInstance;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
          editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          mInstance = this;
      }

      public static synchronized MyActivity getInstance() {
          return mInstance;
      }

      public void setConnectivityListener( ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
           ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
           // register connection status listener
           MyActivity.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
           if(isConnected){
               editText.setText("Connected");
               // TODO: Many Other Stuff
           } else {
               editText.setText("Not Connected");
               // TODO: Many Other Stuff
           }
       }    
       }
  ```
- ConnectivityReceiver

  ```
  public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;

      public ConnectivityReceiver() {
          super();
      }

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
              .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

          if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {                    
                  connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
          }
      }

      public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
          ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
      }

      public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
          void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
      }
  }
  ```
- AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="idiot.houses.contactsimport" >
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher1"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:supportsRtl="true"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <activity
              android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>    
          <receiver
              android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver"
              android:enabled="true">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
              </intent-filter>
          </receiver>    
      </application>    
  </manifest>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Finally after browsing through the internet, I had a way out and thanks to Vincent Aunai for his help

- MyApplication.java

  ```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {

     public static int counterValue=0;

     private static MyApplication mInstance;

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();

          mInstance = this;
      }

      public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
          return mInstance;
      }

      public void setConnectivityListener(ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
          ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
      }
  }
  ```
- MyActivity.java

  ```
  public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {
      private ConnectivityReceiver receiver;
      private EditText editText;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
          editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          receiver=new ConnectivityReceiver();
          IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
          registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
      }
      @Override
      protected void onDestroy(){
          unregisterReceiver(receiver);
      }


       @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
           // register connection status listener
           MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
           if(isConnected){
               editText.setText("Connected");
               // TODO: Many Other Stuff
           } else {
               editText.setText("Not Connected");
               // TODO: Many Other Stuff
           }
       }    
   }
  ```
- ConnectivityReceiver.java

  ```
  public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;

      public ConnectivityReceiver() {
          super();
      }

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {        
          boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
          if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {                    
                  connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
          }
      }

      public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
          ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
      }

      public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
          void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
      }
  }
  ```
- AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="idiot.houses.contactsimport" >
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <application
          android:name=".MyApplication"
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher1"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:supportsRtl="true"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <activity
              android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>    
          <receiver
              android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver"
              android:enabled="true">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
              </intent-filter>
          </receiver>    
      </application>    
  </manifest>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your activity should register your broadcast receiver.

In your `onStart()`, for example, just do the following :

```
public void onStart() {
     ConnectivityReceiver receiver = new ConnectivityReceiver();
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

The filter variable should be the same as declared in your Manifest.

Also, you should unregister your receiver when the activity is no more used :

```
public void onStop() {
       unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}
```